# Prevent Angular $httpProvider interceptor from firing on template loads

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Want a simple interceptor that will fire a logging method on every 200 status.  This was easy to setup, but now I'm noticing that all of my Angular templates are loaded via $httpProvider as well and thus triggering my 200 interceptor.  Any way to differentiate between template loads and actual API calls?

```
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
      return {
          response: function(response) {

              if(response.status === 200) console.log(response);
              return response;
          }
      };
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can. Within the response object, there is a config object and inside config object is the URL of the resource you had requested. So,

```
 $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
      return {
          response: function(response) {

                function endsWith  ( str, suffix ) {
                    return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
                }

              if(response.status === 200 && !endsWith( response.config.url, '.html') ) console.log(response);
              return response;
          }
      };
  });
```